# Not able to set a variable to a path

Tags: sh

am new in writing shell script. When I execute the following program every time I get "**$userInput1=/home/xyx/dest1: No such file or directory**"

```
fun1()
{
    .
    .
    $2=$userInputPath'/*' #$userInputPath holds a path like /home/xyx/dest1 
    .
    .
}
```

Am using Bourne shell and calling the function like the following manner -

```
fun1 $input1 userInput1
```

and after calling the function if I echo $userInput1 it prints nothing. It is to be mentioned that the path /home/xyx/dest1 is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well normally you would use `declare` but it is inside a
function. So if you want access to `userInput1` outside
of the function you will need to do

```
fun1 () {
  read $2 <<< "$userInputPath/*"
}
```